# How to deal with abnormal input and stop running the rest of a function in F#?

Tags: f#

I've been learning F#, and I'm writing a tool in it. Everything works fine except when I need to handle invalid input or exceptional situations.

What is the recommended way of dealing this in F#? The way my functions are constructed and used I'm not sure how to send back a message that tells the calling function that the call failed due to bad input and something similar to C#'s loop continue needs to happen.

I'm suffering due to the loss of Return. Can I return from an F# function anywhere in it, or does it have to be on the last line?

Here is an example of some of my code where the input is in some cases essentially empty, and I am detecting that. I need to prevent the steps in the process that follow from running.

```
let SchemaQueryString s =
    let sqsValid s = 
        let Strcat (x : string) (y : string) = x + ", " + y;
        let RecFieldName (x : MeasurementRecord) = x.FieldName;    
        let mapr = List.map RecFieldName s.MeasurementTypes;
        let cores = List.reduce Strcat mapr;
        "SELECT ProductionCode, TestTime, " + cores + " FROM " + s.TemplateName + " ORDER BY ProductionCode, TestTime";

    match s.MeasurementTypes.Length with
    | 0 -> ""
    | _ -> sqsValid s;

let TemplateMigration tcs rr =
    let sql = SchemaQueryString tcs;
    let sqlc = new SqlCommand(sql, QCOld);
    let sqldr = sqlc.ExecuteReader();
    ignore (sqldr.Read());
    ...
```

I need to abort the TemplateMigration function and return immediately on a match of the sql variable with "". Or construct some kind of union type that indicates that no sql query string could be constructed because for a specific case it couldn't be done.

Thanks for your help. I'm gradually figuring out this language, and I like a lot about it, but I'm struggling with some aspects of it where I don't know how to replace my procedural ideas about how to do something with functional ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using functional languages for the first time many people trip up on the idea that *everything is an expression*. This means that control flow is performed using *control flow expressions*.

So what's the difference between a statement and an expression?

A statement has no value, i.e. it's not an instance of a type. An expression has a value (even if that value is of the special type `unit` which has a single instance *`()`* that represents no value.)

In a procedural language we use statements to control the flow of execution so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;

        if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            return;
        else if (args.Length >= 2)
            str = args[1];
        else
            str = "Hello";

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Here we define a variable `str` of type `string` to have a value `null`. Then we either ignore it and `return` if it's Monday, assign `args[1]` if available or `"Hello"` otherwise and print it.

When  the control flow statement is a few lines long this sort of programming is fairly safe. However as soon as the statement becomes greater than a page long, or complex and nested, we become more likely to introduce errors, typically the [billion dollar mistake](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References:+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake).

Pure functional languages use *control flow expressions* instead. This means that an `if` expression has a value! Let's slowly implement the control in the former code example. First lets tackle the assigning the string `str`.

```
let str =
    if args.Length >= 2 then
        args.[1]
    else 
        "Hello"
```

Here we see that we are directly binding the value of the `if` expression to `str`. Both branches (sub-expressions) of the `if` expression **must** evaluate to an instance of type `string`. We simply can not forget to assign a value to string because the compiler will throw an error should we try.

But it would seem that there are many cases when we wish to do different types of things in different branches of our control flow. In our example if it's Monday we don't want to do anything. This is where the power of *discriminated unions* comes into play. These allow us to combine heterogeneous types into a whole, preserving the power of expression-based languages to type-check our code at every level.

In our case we do not need to create a new union type as the `option` type already encompasses this functionality. We thus rewrite so:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let Main args =

    let str =
        if DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday then
            None
        elif args.Length >= 2 then
            Some(args.[1])
        else 
            Some("Hello")

    match str with
    | Some(str) -> Console.WriteLine(str)
    | None      -> ()

    Environment.ExitCode
```

Now the value we return from our `if` expression is `string option` (or `Option<string>` in C#) and we then use *pattern matching* to safely deal with all possible results of our control flow.

As you are returning the `unit` value from `TemplateMigration` you could simple return the same value from both branches of an `if` expression so:

```
let TemplateMigration tcs rr =
    let sql = SchemaQueryString tcs
    if sql = null || sql.Length = 0 then
        ()
    else 
        let sqlc = new SqlCommand(sql, QCOld)
        let sqldr = sqlc.ExecuteReader()
        ignore (sqldr.Read())
```

However it would probably be better to return an `option` value from `SchemaQueryString`

```
let SchemaQueryString s =
    ... // Elided

    match s.MeasurementTypes.Length with
    | 0 -> None
    | _ -> Some(sqsValid s)
```

to 'propagate' strongly typed values throughout your code.

Answer (score 4):

Someone else has already posted the two best methods for early return: if-then-else (or equivalently a pattern match) and exceptions.  There is a third, which is to author an exception monad and use the F# computation expression syntax to gain an 'implicit return on failure' code path.  This is a much more advanced technique, and I would recommend against it unless you are writing very many if-then-else clauses in many functions, at which point the computation expression may start being a 'win'.

In this particular example, it would be most idiomatic for ScemaQueryString to return a "string option", e.g. have the return be

```
match s.MeasurementTypes.Length with    
| 0 -> None
| _ -> Some(sqsValid s)
```

and then begin the other functions with

```
match SchemaQueryString tcs with
| None -> ()
| Some(sql) -> ... // rest of function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "throw" statement to exit from your code, but F# exception handling is much more heavier than OCaml one (it's not F# quirk, it's .net feature).

Answer (score 0):

As with other languages, you can return at any time. Insert a conditional which returns a special value (-1, "Error", etc.) for bad data, continues processing and returns good data otherwise.

Or use F#'s [exception handling methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233223%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: So if I have a function that returns unit type, can I just do
if condition then () and the function will exit if the condition is met?

Comment: Think about how your code will be evaluated. Functional programming adds some interesting quirks, but for the most part lines are executed sequentially. Control statements such as IF and RETURN interrupt the normal flow. Put the rest of your code inside ELSE, then the code block will have nothing to do but return NULL, a special value that other functions can interpret as invalid data.

Comment: No, you can't just do "if condition then ()" because that will evaluate completely to a unit and be ignored if it's not the last expression. You need an else, that goes to the rest of the function. For example ** let test x = if String.IsNullOrEmpty x then () ; printfn "got a value"; printfn "last bit of work";; ** if you replace else with ;, you'll see you end up printing both lines regardless of the input.